# PHP defined not working?

Tags: php, constants, defined

I have a config file that I include early in my program and set this

```
define('BASE_SLUG','/shop');
```

I include another file later with these lines

```
echo BASE_SLUG;
if (defined(BASE_SLUG)) {
  echo ' - yes';
} else {
  echo ' - no';
}
```

And my output is

```
/shop - no
```

how is this possible?  `BASE_SLUG` has the value of `/shop` and I can echo it, but one line later it says it is not defined

Comment: `if (defined(BASE_SLUG))` = `if (defined('/shop'))` which is not defined.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is the function prototype for `defined`

```
bool defined ( string $name )
```

You can see that it expects a string value for a constant name. Yours isn't a valid string.

```
if (defined(BASE_SLUG)) {
```

Should have the name of constant inside quotes, like :

```
if (defined('BASE_SLUG')) {
```

Read this note from PHP Manual

```
<?php
/* Note the use of quotes, this is important.  This example is checking
 * if the string 'TEST' is the name of a constant named TEST */
if (defined('TEST')) {
    echo TEST;
}
?>
```

**[Source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php)**